# Netty as "proxy": outbound channel with different port number

Tags: java, netty

I implemented a middleware in Netty based on the HexDumpProxy example:

```
BROWSER ------> WEBAPP ------> MW-NETTY ------> SERVER
        [http]         [http]           [tcp]
```

Each customer has a dedicated WEBAPP but the MW-NETTY is a unique instance. The SERVER is listening to different port numbers, one per customer.

From the MW-NETTY, how could I dynamically access the server, with the right port number, using an information in the HTTP header.

As the channels are created before messages arrive, what would be the best strategy to implement it?

Thanks,

--nick

Comment: You will automatically get a new local port per outbound connection. Unclear what your problem is, if any, and what you're asking,

Comment: Let's say all clients use the same mw-netty instance, but for client#1, mw-netty should talk to the server using port number 9999, for client#2, mw-netty should talk to the server using 9997, etc...

Comment: Let's say that why? The client will get a random local port, as I already said. Any effort you make to change that will be fraught with peril.

Comment: OK, I didn't know that, thank you.

Comment: @EJP subject edited to make it clearer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the Socks Proxy example, rather:

https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/4.1/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/socksproxy

This shows how to read a request from the client, extract some information from it that is needed to establish the outbound connection, and then forward packets in either direction.

Comment: Thanks, it should help.

Comment: @NicolasOcquidant It should indeed, but there is nothing there about local ports for outbound connections.

Comment: The Socks example doesn't specify binding a specific local port for outbound connections, that is typically unnecessary. It may still be possible, though, if it is strictly required. By my reading of the question, the specific port is actually on the destination, which is the common usage. And the Socks option shows how to do that quite well.